# Split view in container view loses function of navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, containers, uisplitviewcontroller

i'm building an app for which i need a split view controller. I embedded it in a container view so i could use a segue to acces it. The problem now is that I can't use my navigation bar in a proper way anymore. Normally, there should be a button to go to the previous page, but now I only have the option to go to the homepage (for within the split view controller). You can find some images [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66972SsSRztbVV4MmJKRDE3anM). Also, the title will always be "Shoppen", even though I stated it otherwise.

I suppose the problem is that the navigation bar of the view controller in which the container view is set will always be the top one. I have no idea on how to either delete or fix this problem though, could anybody here help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Some code to show you what it should normally do:

- In the first section, the table view, it should indeed always title "Shoppen" and able to go back to the homepage
- In the detail section, we should be able to go to the table view page, and the title should be the category of the shop we clicked. This is defined here:

  ```
  func configureView() {

  if let detailWinkel = detailWinkel {
      if let detailDescriptionLabel = detailDescriptionLabel, WinkelImageView = WinkelImageView {
          if detailWinkel.name == "Hunkemoller" {
              detailDescriptionLabel.text = "Hunkemöller"
          } else {
          detailDescriptionLabel.text = detailWinkel.name
          }
          WinkelImageView.image = UIImage(named: detailWinkel.name)
          title = detailWinkel.category
          StraatDescriptionLabel.text = detailWinkel.straat
          AdresDescriptionLabel.text = detailWinkel.adres
          WebsiteButton.setTitle("Open website in Safari", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

      }
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to do.

An embed segue is not a normal segue. You can't push a view that is embedded into another view controller onto a navigation stack, if that's what you are saying.

An embed segue is a degenerate case. It invokes the contained view controller at the time the parent view controller is loaded, and there is no mechanism for going back.

Comment: Well, what i'm trying to do here is: I have a homepage held in a navigation controller. This homepage leads to a few different subjects, in this case: shopping. This shopping page holds a list of the different shops in our neigbourhood, and provides a detailed page about each of the shops, hence the detail page in the split view controller.

I couldn't use a segue directly to the split view controller though, so i set up a container and embedded the whole split view into it, because i didn't know how i'd have to do it otherwise... I added a video of how the app works into the drive.

Comment: And i guess the embedding inside the container is the problem, because that becomes the only navigation bar visible